# Filter nodes by entity reference

Tags: 8, views

I have an `article` content type linked to an `event` content type via entity reference.

In the `Articles` view, I would like to offer a filter allowing to filter articles by linked event title.

With Drupal 7, we used to manage it with [better_exposed_filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module but I can't find a way to do it in Drupal 8.

Comment: The core issue to fix this is [Generalize TaxonomyIndexTid filter to be available for all entity reference fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the my solution inspired from:

- http://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-filter-drupal-8
- http://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/

Thanks to Danny Sipos

I already had a dedicated custom module for this project where I added the following:

`mymodule.views.inc`

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(array &$data)
{
    $data['node_field_data']['related_content_titles'] = array(
        'title' => t('Related content titles'),
        'filter' => array(
            'title' => t('Related content titles'),
            'help' => t('Specify a list of titles an content node can have.'),
            'field' => 'nid',
            'id' => 'mymodule_related_content_titles'
        ),
    );
}
```

`src/Plugin/views/filter/RelatedContentTitles.php`

```
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\ManyToOne;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Filters by given list of event title options.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("mymodule_related_content_titles")
 */
class RelatedContentTitles extends ManyToOne
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL)
    {
        parent::init($view, $display, $options);
        $this->valueTitle = t('Allowed event titles');
        $this->definition['options callback'] = array($this, 'generateOptions');
    }

    /**
     * Helper function that generates the options.
     * @return array
     */
    public function generateOptions()
    {
        $storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');

        $relatedContentQuery = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('type', array('event', 'story'), 'IN')
            ->condition('status', 1);

        $relatedContentIds = $relatedContentQuery->execute();

        $res = array();
        foreach ($relatedContentIds as $contentId) {
            $res[$contentId] = $storage->load($contentId)->getTitle();
        }

        return $res;
    }
}
```

When ceating the view listing my articles where I want to expose the `related event` filter I had to :

- add a relationship `field_article_associated_event: Content`
- add a filter criteria of my type `Related content titles`, select the perviously cerated relationship for the field `Relationshi`, check `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it`

Comment: Explained a bit more in details here:
http://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2015/10/06/entity-reference-filter-with-drupal-8

Comment: Can this code be used to help fix the core issue over at https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699 ?

Comment: Worked great - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Entity Reference Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_exposed_filters) module.

> A module for those who need their Entity Reference Exposed Filters to have titles in Select Lists.